# ASP.net update DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm adding a value database table then i want to show on DropDownList. This code working when page is loading. But when i add new value to db, dropdownlist doesn't update. I called after adding value but doesn't change. When i don't use !IsPostBack, dropdownlist updating but in this case DataValueField doesnt working.

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            .............
            listStudent.DataSource = dt;
            listStudent.DataTextField = "st";
            listStudent.DataValueField = "id";
            listStudent.DataBind();
        }
```

Comment: If the value is added in the database, just add a new `dt` to `listStudent` and databind it...

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are free to put the DataTextField and the DataValue field in the markup.
(but does not matter one bit at all).

So, say we have this markup:
(drop down, and a button to add a new value).

```
   <asp:DropDownList ID="cboHotels" runat="server" 
        DataValueField="HotelName" DataTextField="HotelName" AutoPostBack="True" Width="174px" >
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:Button ID="cmdAdd" runat="server" Text="+" style="margin-left:10px"
        OnClick="cmdAdd_Click"
        OnClientClick="return AddHotel();" />

    <asp:TextBox ID="txtHotelName" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" style="display:none"></asp:TextBox>
    <script>
        function AddHotel() {

            myhotel = prompt("Enter New Hotel Name")
            if (myhotel != null) {
                document.getElementById('txtHotelName').value = myhotel
                return true
            }
            else {
                return false
            }
            }
    </script>
```

So, we have that "+" button beside the drop to add a new row to the database.

So, our code to fill the drop down looks like this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack == false)
            LoadCombo();
    }

    public void LoadCombo()
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT HotelName from tblHotels ORDER BY HotelName",
                                    new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4)))
        {
            cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
            cboHotels.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader();
            cboHotels.DataBind();
            // add a blank (no select row)
            cboHotels.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(""));
        }
    }
```

And our code to add a new row looks like this:

```
    protected void cmdAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // add a new hotel to table
        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL =
            new SqlCommand("INSERT into tblHotels (HotelName) Values(@Hotel)",
            new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.AccessDB)))
        {
            cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Hotel", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtHotelName.Text;
            cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        LoadCombo();   // re-load combo to show new row

        // lets be nice and select the row we just added
        cboHotels.ClearSelection();
        cboHotels.Items.FindByText(txtHotelName.Text).Selected = true;
    }
```

And we get this:

[image]